# Meteor automatic refresh on app restart

Tags: javascript, meteor

Meteor automatically refreshes all tabs for all connected clients when the server restarts. I need to control that functionality so that it refreshes slower and gives notice of what's happening.

I found the code in the source in the livedata package, but is there some way to control it without hacking the core package.

Comment: Why? The state of the webpage is maintained and then restored after the refresh isn't it?

Comment: @Swadq Various user input fields are not, unless I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Indeed, certain user input fields aren't. Perhaps it would be better to develop a package that maintains them than delay the refresh?

Comment: Aren't the input fields supposed to be taken care of with `preserve-inputs`?

Comment: How to make the app that auto refresh the page when the Data is inserted in the DB  ?? or i can say is that how to make the Reactive app with the meteor ??

Answer (score 2):

There is a private API in packages/reload/reload.js to do this. Since the API is private it might change, but here is how it works:

Example:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {

  var firstTime = true;

  function onMigrate (retry) {
    if (firstTime) {
      console.log("retrying migration in 3 seconds");
      firstTime = false;
      Meteor.setTimeout(function () {
        retry();
      }, 3000);
      return false;
    } else {
      return [true];
    }
  }

  Meteor._reload.onMigrate("someName", onMigrate);

  // or Meteor._reload.onMigrate(onMigrate);

}
```

From the comments in `packages/reload/reload.js`:

> Packages that support migration should register themselves by calling
>   this function. When it's time to migrate, callback will be called with
>   one argument, the "retry function." If the package is ready to
>   migrate, it should return [true, data], where data is its migration
>   data, an arbitrary JSON value (or [true] if it has no migration data
>   this time). If the package needs more time before it is ready to
>   migrate, it should return false. Then, once it is ready to migrating
>   again, it should call the retry function. The retry function will
>   return immediately, but will schedule the migration to be retried,
>   meaning that every package will be polled once again for its migration
>   data. If they are all ready this time, then the migration will happen.
>   name must be set if there is migration data.